# How to find the similar sentence based on keyword that does not directly appear in sentences?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I need to return a text that contain the keyword. Let's consider the following example:

```
keyword = "configure"
texts = [ 
   "The system configuration document should be uploaded to the repository. Please contact the dev team.",
   "To do the system setup, please follow the instructions." 
]
```

The keyword `configure` does not appear in any text. But the similar word `configuration` appears in the first sentence. Therefore the expected output is:

```
The system configuration document should be uploaded to the repository. Please contact the dev team.
```

I know that it's possible to calculate the [semantic similarity between a word and texts][1]. However, it often returns inaccurate results for my case.

Another approach that I was evaluating is to apply stemming and lemmatization. However, `configure` and `configuration` have different stems.

Finally I also considered `Word2Vec` model... However, in this case I'm not sure how to efficiently use this approach.

```
import gensim.downloader as api

word_vectors = api.load("glove-wiki-gigaword-100") 

word_vectors.similarity("configure","configuration")
```

Is there any state-of-the-art approach to deal with my task?
[1]: https://medium.com/@adriensieg/text-similarities-da019229c894

Comment: Hey did you find a good solution for this yet?

Answer (score 0):

If your sentences' lengths are not too long, you can try to sum words' vectors in the sentence and then search similarity between your keyword and this sum.

Otherwise, you can try to extract keywords from the sentence and then sum their vectors for searching the closest your keyword.

Comment: In your scenario how can I be sure that the closest vector has the same root? For example, in some sentence, the word that is closest to `activate` could be `restart`, but this would not be correct for me. I only need to get the texts that contain keywords with the same root. Do you know how can I get roots of words (not stemming)?

Comment: Actually, `activate` is not the best example. Let's take `diagnose`, `diagnosis` and `diagnostic`. If I do stemming, I get `diagnos`, `diagnosi` and `diagnost`... How can I get  `diagnos` (the shortest one) for all of them to be able to compare them?

Comment: Try to watch `polyglot` library, it can extract word morphemes such as root, suffix, ending... https://polyglot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/MorphologicalAnalysis.html